# Set key and value of a map* in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary

I am following http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/.

I am trying to build an invert index structure, which is a map that has a 64 bits integer as a key and **each key will hold a pointer to a sub-map**. A sub-map will contain int int pair. So I got myself writing some samples:

```
map<unsigned long long int, map<int, int>*> invertID;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    map<int,int>* m = new map<int,int>();

    m[10] = 1;

    invertID[1] = m;

    return 0;

}
```

But here is the trouble, normally, for a non-pointer type map like

```
std::map<char,int> first;
```

as described in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/, I see that we can do

```
first['a']= 10;
```

But **if we have a pointer type for map, how can we do that?** My code above will generate an error complaining

```
error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can de-reference the pointer:

```
 (*m)[10] = 1;
```

or

```
m->operator[](10) = 1;
```

On the other hand, do you really need all these pointers? Would your program suffer greatly from using this form?

```
map<unsigned long long int, map<int, int>> invertID;
int main()
{
    map<int,int> m;
    invertID[1][10] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Wait, so you are suggesting me to just insert the sub-map into the map, not as a pointer? What if I wanna modify this sub-map later? Does that mean, in binary, the program will have to create a copy of this sub-map, change some values, and replace the original sub-map in the main map with the modified copy of sub-map? Is there performance penalty?

Comment: @Karl you just access it via `invertID[index]`. I added an example.

Answer (score 2):

Map is a red-black tree where operations so you use that to get best performance for search and insert..etc. You are using map not Multi-map in invertID. Thus when you fetch certain key in most cases I would assume you looking for pair of elements. unless you have a need for second map for whatever reason I am not thinking of now, I would go for this:

```
std::map < unsigned long long int, std::pair < int , int >  > invertID;
int main(){
    std::pair<int,int>  m;
    m = std::make_pair(1,2);
    invertID[1] = m;
    return 0;
}
```

Have fun.

Comment: the sub-map is used for counting the frequency (an integer) of the document ID (also an integer).

Comment: then go for pair, much easier and faster. and up-vote me please as I am blocked

Comment: but the frequency of each document ID will be increment during the runtime. Can we modify the value of the pair too?

Comment: of course. with .first and .second member functions. check this for you: http://pastebin.com/kjd7cvZW

Comment: I took a closer look into pair at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/, I see that a pair will only contain two values. It seems my explanation is not that good in the beginning. The reason that I used a map in a map is because in each index of invert index, it may hold more than 1 pair in some occasions.

Comment: then multi-map Karl not map.